# Aws get-metric-statistic datapoint is null

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I have been using aws cli to get metrics statistic, but when I run this command, datapoint is null, my command is:

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --metric-name CPUUtilization --start-time 10:00:00 --end-time 10:05:00 --period 30 --namespace AWS/EC2 --statistics Maximum --dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=i-0d6f3611e2685f0c8
```

and when I run the following command, data point is null
[Datapoint Null image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsNJt.png) , or is there any configuration needed before using get-metric-statistic?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `start-time` and `end-time` in ISO 8601 UTC format not just the time. Example: `2018-08-01T10:00:00Z`.

Also, make sure you are specifying a proper period as described in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-metric-statistics.html).

> If the StartTime parameter specifies a time stamp that is greater than
>   3 hours ago, you must specify the period as follows or no data points
>   in that time range is returned:
>
> - Start time between 3 hours and 15 days ago - Use a multiple of 60 seconds (1 minute).
> - Start time between 15 and 63 days ago - Use a multiple of 300 seconds (5 minutes).
> - Start time greater than 63 days ago - Use a multiple of 3600 seconds (1 hour).

You can change start time/end time to include the date you want. In your case the following command should work:

`aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --metric-name CPUUtilization --start-time 2018-08-01T10:00:00Z --end-time 2018-08-01T10:05:00Z --period 60 --namespace AWS/EC2 --statistics Maximum --dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=i-0d6f3611e2685f0c8`